# liferay get cookies in freemarker template

Tags: templates, cookies, liferay, freemarker

I'm using Liferay 6.2. I have an article that uses freemarker template. In this template I would like to get cookies. I'm trying to do this like this:

```
${httpUtil.getCookies()}
```

But i only get this error:

```
Expression httpUtil.getCookies() is undefined on line 18, column 31 in 10157#10197#ARTICLE-1.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

How to make it work?

Comment: According the error message the `httpUtil.getCookies()` method itself is defined, it just returns null. (Such things can be written as `httpUtil.cookes` BTW, but that will be also undefined.)

Comment: @ddekany Yes, it is defined, liferay template editor give hints that I can use such method, but it returns null despite I see plenty of cookies in browser developer tools for my page. It's liferay's httpUtil fault I think, but maybe someone know a proper way to get cookies.

Comment: This is probably due to restricted variables for freemarker.